# Send table data to popup delete

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to delete a field in my html table. When I click on the delete button I redirect the user to a popup window asking if they are sure if they want to delete that line in the table. Once they click yes it takes them to a delete.php file which deletes it from our database. I am not sure how I can send this value to our delete.php file.

```
  <!-- /.row -->
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
  <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>User Name</th>
   <th>Distinct Items</th>
   <th>Total Occurrences</th>
   <th>Last Occurrence</th>
   <th>Environment</th>
   <th>Control</th>
    </tr>
      </thead>
       <tbody>


      <?php

        include ("config.php");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM newTable";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['account_id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['user'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['pass'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['privs'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['privValue'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<a href="#Modal_modify" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>';
        echo '<a href="#Modal_delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></a>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    } 
?>





 <!-- Modal_delete HTML -->
        <div id="Modal_delete" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete User</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this user?</p>
                    </div>

                    <form action="delete_user.php" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"/>
                       <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is to create the delete button I am referencing an html subroutine to create that the popup once that is clicked. How can I send the the table data to my delete.php file?

```
<?php
include ("test.php");

$tbl_name="newTable"; // Table name 

$id = $_POST['id'];

echo $_POST['id'];

echo "$id";
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)

$sql="DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE account_id='$id';";
mysql_query(sql);

header("Location: adminUser.php");




?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you opposed to using jquery?  (And sorry, I would ask that in a comment beforehand, but, tsk, not enough reputation, so here's my whole answer :) The following would be very simple:

```
$('.btn-danger').click(function(event) {
    $('#Modal_delete').css('display', 'initial'); // swap this for however you're showing your delete confirmation popup.  I just had it for testing.
    var rowToDeleteID = $(event.currentTarget).parents('tr').attr('id'); // you'd need to add a unique id to each table row for this to work.
    $('input[type="hidden"]').val(rowToDeleteID);
});
```

Of course, this would be much more robust (in fact, depending on your other code, it might *only* work [not to mention it's just a good idea]) if you add unique identifiers to the delete buttons (the a tags with fa-trash-o icons) and your hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$row['account_id']` as an attribute in the link `#Modal_delete` and get it with jQuery..

```
<a href="#Modal_delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-account-id="<?= $row['account_id'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></a>

$("a[href='#Modal_delete']").on("click", function(e) {
    $("input[name='id']").val($(this).data("account-id"));
});
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the input so I should use jquery to get that value. How would I actually send it to my php file though?

Comment: You just submit the form as you are doing today. The `$_POST["id"]` will get the new value from the hidden input `name='id'`. And you can remove the `value="<?php echo $id;?>"` from the id input.

Comment: hmm I added what you said and the value is still not being passed

Comment: take a look at [this example](http://jsbin.com/mebuvehugira/1/edit?html,js,output)